# Loop DynamicObject properties

Tags: c#, dynamicobject

I'm trying to understand the DynamicObject type. Found this MSDN article to be very consise and clear as how to create and use DynamicObject:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx

The article contains a simple DynamicDictionary class that inherits from DynamicObject.

Now I want to iterate over my dynamically created DynamicObject properties:

```
dynamic d = new DynamicDictionary();
d.Name = "Myname";
d.Number = 1080;

foreach (var prop in d.GetType().GetProperties())
{
  Console.Write prop.Key;
  Console.Write prop.Value;
}
```

Obviously that does not work. I want to learn how to do this without a change in my DynamicDictionary class, since I'm really trying to learn how to use this for all kinds of existing objects that inherits from DynamicObject.

Is Reflection needed? I must be missing something...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Did you tried DynamicDictionary.GetDynamicMemberNames() method? - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.getdynamicmembernames.aspx

Comment: Looks good - but I dont want to / cannot change my class and "GetDynamicMemberNames() is an optional thing, i.e. a class inheriting from DynamicObject can override it if it wants, but if it doesn't the function in the base class gets called which returns an empty list."

Comment: Hmm I understand. Then I think either you need to go for ExpandoObject or you need it implement it your own.

Answer (score 53):

I believe you'd be interested in the [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) class.  The `DynamicObject` class is just a base where you're meant to provide all the logic.  It explicitly implements the `IDictionary<string, object>` interface so you can access it properties or add new ones that way.

```
// declare the ExpandoObject
dynamic expObj = new ExpandoObject();
expObj.Name = "MyName";
expObj.Number = 1000;

// print the dynamically added properties
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in expObj) // enumerating over it exposes the Properties and Values as a KeyValuePair
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);

// cast to an IDictionary<string, object>
IDictionary<string, object> expDict = expObj;

// add a new property via the dictionary reference
expDict["Foo"] = "Bar";

// verify it's been added on the original dynamic reference
Console.WriteLine(expObj.Foo);
```

---

I had just realized that you are implementing the `DynamicDictionary` class and misunderstood your question.  Sorry.

When used with a dynamic reference, you only have access to publicly exposed members.  Since only `Count` is declared public (besides the other `DynamicObject` members), you'd need to use reflection in order to access the inner dictionary to easily get those values (if you don't intend to make any further changes).

Comment: Ok, thanks, so - for an existing object which inherits DynamicObject and does not expose the dictionary - there's no way for me (other than to use Reflection) to get the members dictionary?

Comment: AFAIK yes.  You're only able to access public members and the `DynamicObject` class where member access is resolved through the various methods.  Alternatively, you could explicitly implement the `IDictionary<string, object>` class just like the ExpandoObject to make this process easier.

Comment: p.s., Sorry I glossed over your question at first.  I didn't notice that you were actually implementing the example code.  I was thinking to myself, "There's no `DynamicDictionary` class..."  :)

Comment: The part of the answer that does not answer the question is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I know this topic is pretty old but for those who are still wondering on how to do it, why not use the `TryGetMember()` method but construct a class that inherits the `GetMemberBinder`, like:

```
public class MyGetMemberBinder : GetMemberBinder
{
    public MyGetMemberBinder(string name, bool ignorecase) : base(name, ignorecase) { }
    public override DynamicMetaObject FallbackGetMember(DynamicMetaObject target, DynamicMetaObject errorSuggestion)=>throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Then with LINQ:

```
Dictionary<string, object> AsStandardDictionary = DynamicDictionary.GetDynamicMemberNames().ToDictionary(x => x, y =>
{
    if(DynamicDictionary.TryGetMember(new MyGetMemberBinder(y, false), out var result))
        return result;
    else
        return null;
});
```