# C# Accessing a dynamic member of a JObject class using a variable

Tags: c#, json, reflection, json.net

I've got a JObject class and the members are dynamic, but I don't know how to access the dynamic member when the member name is stored in a variable.

Code is below.

```
 dynamic deserializedProduct = JObject.Parse(json);
 string[] user = emailBox.Text.Split('@');
 string pass = deserializedProduct.user[0].password;
 MessageBox.Show(pass);

// User[0] represents the member name
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631546/get-property-value-from-c-sharp-dynamic-object-by-string-reflection

Comment: Moreover don't forget JObject has string indexer too to access properties by name.

Answer (score 0):

if it is dynamic you should be able to access it as if it was just an property

deserializedProduct .user

but I guess you need the value inside the var user.

And in that case there are great utilities from westwind which extend the Expando objects.

check 
http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Feb/08/Creating-a-dynamic-extensible-C-Expando-Object

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Adriano in comment, `JObject` has string indexer. It is more suitable to use that indexer, instead of pushing to do this in common object property name style :

```
........  
string pass = ((dynamic)deserializedProduct[user[0]]).password;
//or full string indexer style
//string pass = deserializedProduct[user[0]]["password"];
MessageBox.Show(pass);
```