# IDynamicMetaObjectProvider set property using literal name

Tags: c#, dynamic

I need to set DynamicObject property using string propertyName. I found the way to get property value using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14011692/1099716), but when it comes to setValue I'm not quite sure how to rewrite the code in order to set the property. I receive runtime errors and not quite sure about expressions logic. I wonder if you can suggest any idea how to implement `void SetProperty(object o, string member,object value)` method.

Comment: The code you link to uses reflection, not `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`, surely?

Comment: First part of the linked code (where provider!=null) is what I'm interested in.

Comment: yeah, but that's still doing things the hard way... and it doesn't benefit from any caching (plus `Compile` and `DynamicInvoke` each time... yeuch); seriously; the `CallSiteCache` code shown works fine... basically it sub-contracts all this mess to the provider/call-site, and caches the strategy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some cases like `ExpandoObject`, then you can use the `IDictionary<string,object>` API instead:

```
ExpandoObject obj = ...
var dict =  (IDictionary<string, object>)obj;
object oldVal = dict[memberName];
dict[memberName] = newVal;
```

In the more general case of `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`: you could borrow the `CallSiteCache` from FastMember:

```
internal static class CallSiteCache
{
    private static readonly Hashtable getters = new Hashtable(), setters = new Hashtable();

    internal static object GetValue(string name, object target)
    {
        CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object>> callSite = (CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object>>)getters[name];
        if (callSite == null)
        {
            lock (getters)
            {
                callSite = (CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object>>)getters[name];
                if (callSite == null)
                {
                    CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object>> newSite = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object>>.Create(Binder.GetMember(CSharpBinderFlags.None, name, typeof(CallSiteCache), new CSharpArgumentInfo[] { CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null) }));
                    getters[name] = callSite = newSite;
                }
            }
        }
        return callSite.Target(callSite, target);
    }
    internal static void SetValue(string name, object target, object value)
    {
        CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object, object>> callSite = (CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object, object>>)setters[name];
        if (callSite == null)
        {
            lock (setters)
            {
                callSite = (CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object, object>>)setters[name];
                if (callSite == null)
                {
                    CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object, object>> newSite = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object, object>>.Create(Binder.SetMember(CSharpBinderFlags.None, name, typeof(CallSiteCache), new CSharpArgumentInfo[] { CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null), CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.UseCompileTimeType, null) }));
                    setters[name] = callSite = newSite;
                }
            }
        }
        callSite.Target(callSite, target, value);
    }
}
```

Note here that we *could* type `target` as  `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`, but we don't actually need that - the `CallSite` API doesn't require it.

Comment: Work pretty good, thanks :) Had to change Hashtable to Dictionary, because I need it in PCL, but it was not a big deal.

Comment: @AccessDenied important note: dictionary has different thread-safety semantics to `Hashtable`; if you have made that swap, you can no longer safely do the first check outside the `lock`; basically: move everything **inside** the `lock`; obviously there would be no point in double-checked locking in that case either

Comment: But why can't we apply double check lock with dictionary?

Comment: @AccessDenied there's no point if you are already inside the lock.... the *definition* of double-checked is: to check outside the lock, lock, check inside the lock, then *do the thing*; if you **must** lock, there's no point checking twice inside; it isn't going to change because *you have the lock*

Comment: Could you be so kind to take a look at my code snippet and tell me what is wrong with it? Can't get what is wrong with it. http://codeshare.io/J5RpN

Comment: @AccessDenied simple: it isn't thread-safe; `TryGetValue` can fail if the dictionary is being mutated by a competing thread (meaning: the `TryGetValue` that is *outside* the `lock`)