# Getting Property from ExpandoObject causing error

Tags: c#, expandoobject

I have an Expando Object ("points") with a property called "in".  There is another property called "duration".  **points.duration** returns as expected, but **points.in** throws ***error CS1001: Identifier expected***.  I can't change the name of the property right now, so how can I get the value without throwing the error.  I'm assuming this has to do with some kind of keyword conflict.

```
 foreach (dynamic? point in points)
 {
     PointModel model = new PointModel
     {
         InPoint = point.in,
         Duration = point.duration,
         PointType = point.type
     };
    
     //other code here.
 }
```

Comment: Done - as requested.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a better way, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8631546/328193) (and others to which it links) could be helpful.

Comment: `InPoint = ((IDictionary<String, Object>)point)["in"];` ?

Comment: [@in](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AtMaB7)